# Nuxt: using `optional chaining operator` operator (.?)

Tags: javascript, babeljs, nuxt.js

Nuxt 2.12.2 throw error on build when trying to use `object?.key`.

```sh
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (311:25)                                                                                                                                                 friendly-errors 10:36:40
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file
```

So it because `babel` in Nuxt configured to support older browsers like `IE9` that I did not need in my project.

In another project, I just put `.bablelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 Chrome versions"]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

but in Nuxt `.bablelrc` are disabled. so how can I make `optional chaining operator` work ?

by telling Nuxt to support just modern browsers. or added the `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`

Answer (score 22):

As [Nuxtjs Doc](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/) describe, `.babelrc` is ignored by default.

I solved this question by the below config.

```js
// in nuxt.config.js
{
  // ...
  build: {
    // ....
    babel: {
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, before that, you should install `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`

```sh
npm i -D @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Can I somehow use it in npm run dev?

Answer (score 8):

Try [vue-template-babel-compiler](https://github.com/JuniorTour/vue-template-babel-compiler)

It uses `Babel` to enable `Optional Chaining(?.)`, `Nullish Coalescing(??)` and many new ES syntax for `Vue.js SFC`.

### [Github Repo: vue-template-babel-compiler](https://github.com/JuniorTour/vue-template-babel-compiler)

### DEMO

[image: DEMO Image]

### Usage

#### 1. Install

```sh
npm install vue-template-babel-compiler --save-dev
```

#### 2. Config

##### 1. [Vue-CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-loader)

[DEMO project for Vue-CLI](https://github.com/JuniorTour/vue-template-babel-compiler-vue-cli-project)

##### 2. [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/configuration#extend-webpack-to-load-audio-files)

[DEMO project for Nuxt.js](https://github.com/JuniorTour/vue-template-babel-compiler-nuxt-project)

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    loaders: {
      vue: {
        compiler: require('vue-template-babel-compiler')
      }
    },
  },
  // ...
}
```

[Please refer to REAMDE for detail usage](https://github.com/JuniorTour/vue-template-babel-compiler#usage)

Support  for `Vue-CLI, Nuxt.js, Webpack` , any environment use `vue-loader v15+`.

Comment: It is not working with nodev16

Comment: @Bravo What error you got? If you got: `Vue packages version mismatch: - vue@2.7.14 - vue-server-renderer@2.6.14` . You can try `npm install vue-server-renderer@2.7.14 --save`. If not ,welcome to create an issue to https://github.com/JuniorTour/vue-template-babel-compiler/issues , This project is still under maintain, your error will be fixed ASAP.